# Exim log and send all mail for a given domain through another server

Tags: email, exim, smtp, greylisting

I administer a handful of shared web hosting servers. Recently, [Yahoo has been deprioritizing/greylising](http://www.ahfx.net/weblog/107) all email sent from these servers. I am getting the dereaded `421 4.7.0 [TS02] Messages from my.ip.address temporarily deferred` message from Yahoo and their postmaster has been unresponsive.

I am unable to find any way to set up a [feedback loop like AOL has](http://postmaster.aol.com/fbl/fblinfo.html) for my IP address -- I did find a way to set up a feedback loop for a given domain, but we host hundreds of domains, and don't have the time to set up that many feedback loops. So what I'd like to do is twofold:

1. Configure Exim to send all email
   destined to an @yahoo.com address to
   a relay, a new server which has an
   IP that yahoo is not blocking.
2. Configure Exim (or maybe the relay)
   to log all emails sent to
   @yahoo.com, so I can review them
   and, in case one of my uses is
   violating ToS and sending SPAM to
   yahoo users, take the appropriate
   action.

How could I accomplish these? Or, does anyone have any other advice for how to get mail to flow through Yahoo and ensure that any email generating complaints is brought to my attention? (For what it's worth, these servers are not listed on any major blacklists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Exim to relay, you want to do something like the following in the "Router" config section:

```
  send_to_other_server:
      driver = manualroute
      domains = !+local_domains
      transport = remote_smtp
      route_list = yahoo.com TheRelay.Mail.Server
```

Obviously you need to allow relaying from your sending server's IP address on the relaying server before this will work.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm actually switching to postfix now, but this might come in handy later on!